# Solver for some simple tangrams

Tags: python, python-3.x, computational-geometry, matplotlib, opencv

I decided to write a program to solve Tangram puzzles. This went a bit out of hand and I ended up with 600+ lines of code. I don't think it should have taken so much code.

Here is an image of a positive result:

[image: (original image from http://www.supercoloring.com/puzzle-games/)]

**Problem sources**

The problems to be solved are `.png` images, I found on the web, of 480x480 pixels with a white background and tangram figures in various colours, details can be found in function `get_random_image`.

**Algorithm**

The algorithm used isn't ideal: it successfully finds a solution in only a small part of my test set. It depends (among others) on allowed distance differences (`EPSILON` in the code).  For the purposes of this review, I am satisfied with a heuristic that does not solve all cases.

- Find corners points (using OpenCV)
- Find edges and more interesting points
- Find small triangles
- Find possible tangram pieces positions from the small triangles
- Find the combination of pieces such that all triangles are 'covered'

**Questions**

- I like PEP8, however I like also to deviate from it for sake of readability in cases such as:

  ```
  if (        condition_1
      and     condition_2
      and not condition_3):
  ```

  Am I using white space correctly and/or readable?
- I don't like to write classes in Python (mainly because of typing all the `self.` everywhere) but are my classes sensible?

(I know it's long, that's part of the problem, the fun part is the `solve` method of `TangramSolver`)

**Code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import product, permutations, combinations
from collections import namedtuple


# some 'constants'
EPSILON       = 0.2
EPSILON_ANGLE = 3.0
ZERO          = 0.0
ONE           = 1.0
TWO           = 2 * ONE
FOUR          = 2 * TWO
SQ2           = np.sqrt(TWO)
SQ10          = np.sqrt(10.0)

FIND_REPEATS  = 1
MAX_LENGTHS   = 6
SPLITS        = {}
for lengths in product([ZERO, SQ2, TWO], repeat=MAX_LENGTHS):
    length = sum(lengths)
    splits = list(lengths)[:-1]
    if not length in SPLITS:
        SPLITS[length] = set()
    for split in np.cumsum(splits):
        if split > 0.0 and split < length:
            SPLITS[length].add(split)
NICE_LENGTHS = list(SPLITS.keys())
NICE_LENGTHS.sort()


class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):
    '''
    Point class...
    '''

    _epsilon = EPSILON
    _format_str = '({:>6.03f},{:>6.03f})'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format_str.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ( abs(self.x - other.x) < Point._epsilon and
                 abs(self.y - other.y) < Point._epsilon      )

    def __hash__(self):
        # return always the same hash, forcing dict and set always
        # to use __eq__
        return 0

    def set_epsilon(eps):
        Point._epsilon = eps

    @property
    def length(self):
        return np.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point( self.x + other.x, 
                      self.y + other.y  )

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point( self.x - other.x, 
                      self.y - other.y  )    

    def __mul__(self, factor):
        return Point( self.x * factor, self.y * factor)

    def distance(self, other):
        return (self - other).length

    def dot_product(self, other):
        return self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y

    def cross_product(self, other):
        return self.x * other.y - self.y * other.x


class Line(namedtuple('Line', ['p1', 'p2'])):

    _format_str = '{} → {}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format_str.format(repr(self.p1), repr(self.p2))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (    (self.p1, self.p2) == (other.p1, other.p2)
                 or (self.p1, self.p2) == (other.p2, other.p1) )

    def __hash__(self):
        # return always the same hash, forcing dict and set always
        # to use __eq__
        return 0

    @property
    def length(self):
        return (self.p2 - self.p1).length

    def angle(self, other=None):
        if not other:
            other = Line(Point(0.0, 0.0), Point(1.0, 0.0))
        v1 = self.p2 - self.p1
        v2 = other.p2 - other.p1
        l1 = v1.length
        l2 = v2.length
        if l1 > 0.0 and l2 > 0.0:
            val = v1.dot_product(v2) / (l1 * l2)
            val = min( 1.0, val)
            val = max(-1.0, val)
            phi = np.arccos (val)
            return 180 * phi / np.pi
        else:
            return None

    def point_along(self, distance):
        vect = (self.p2 - self.p1) 
        vect = vect * (1.0 / vect.length)
        return self.p1 + vect * distance


class Triangle(namedtuple('Triangle', ['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])):

    _format_str = '{} ᐊ {} ᐊ {}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format_str.format(repr(self.p1), 
                                       repr(self.p2),
                                       repr(self.p3),)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (     self.p1 in other
                 and self.p2 in other
                 and self.p3 in other)

    def __hash__(self):
        # return always the same hash, forcing dict and set always
        # to use __eq__
        return 0

    @property             
    def center(self):
        third = 1.0 / 3.0
        return self.p1 * third + self.p2 * third + self.p3 * third  

    def is_inside(self, point):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def is_neighbour(self, other):
        '''
        checks if other triangle is a neighbour, ie. if it has
        two mutual corner points
        '''
        count = 0
        if other.p1 in self: count += 1
        if other.p2 in self: count += 1
        if other.p3 in self: count += 1
        return count == 2 #and not self.is_inside(other.center) 


class Piece(namedtuple('PieceBase', ['corners', 'triangles'])):

    _format_str = 'Piece:\n{}\n{}'

    def __init__(self, corners, triangles):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format_str.format(repr(self.corners), 
                                       repr(self.triangles))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return set(self) == set(other)

    def is_inside(self, test_point):
        N = len(self.corners)
        cross_products = []
        for i in range(N):
            p1 = self.corners[i]
            p2 = self.corners[(i+1) % N]
            v1 = p2 - p1
            v2 = test_point - p1
            cross_products.append(v1.cross_product(v2))
        pos = [c >= 0.0 for c in cross_products] 
        neg = [c <= 0.0 for c in cross_products]
        return all(pos) or all(neg) 

    def ouside_triangles(self, triangles):
        '''
        returns the triangles which center is outside this piece
        '''
        return [t for t in triangles if not self.is_inside(t.center)]


class Tangram():

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.set_image(filename)
        self.set_gray()
        self.set_scale()
        self.set_height()
        self.set_up_plot()

    def set_image(self, filename):
        self.image = cv2.imread(filename)

    def set_gray(self):
        self.gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.blurred = cv2.blur(self.gray, (5,5))

    def set_scale(self):
        # background is 255 in our case, we count the none background
        # pixels, this correspons to the 4 x 4 = 16 tangram surface
        mask = self.gray < 250
        mask.ravel()
        pixels = np.sum(mask)
        self.scale = np.sqrt(pixels / 16.0)    

    def set_height(self):
        self.height = self.gray.shape[1]

    def get_corners(self):
        points = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(
            self.gray, 
            maxCorners = 100, 
            qualityLevel = 0.01, 
            minDistance = 5,
        )
        points = points[:,0,:] # re-arange a bit
        return [self.to_tangram_coor(Point(*p)) for p in points]

    def to_tangram_coor(self, point):
        ix, iy = point.x, point.y
        tx = ix / self.scale
        ty = (self.height - iy) / self.scale
        return Point(tx, ty)

    def to_image_coor(self, point):
        tx, ty = point.x, point.y
        ix = tx * self.scale
        iy = self.height - ty * self.scale
        return Point(int(ix), int(iy))

    def valid_value_at(self, point):
        '''
        check if the point is in tangram and not in the background
        '''
        point = self.to_image_coor(point)
        value = self.blurred[point.y, point.x]
        return value != 255

    def set_up_plot(self):
        '''
        create a plot and add some stuff to it
        '''
        # set matplotlib up,... interactive, delete old plots
        plt.ion()
        plt.close('all')
        self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(ncols=5,
                                           nrows=2,
                                           figsize=(20,10))
        self.axes = self.axes.flatten()
        self.axes[ 0].set_title('original image')
        self.axes[ 1].set_title('initial points & edges')
        self.axes[ 2].set_title('all points')
        self.axes[ 3].set_title('all triangles')
        self.axes[ 4].set_title('solution')
        self.axes[ 5].set_title('big triangles')
        self.axes[ 6].set_title('squares')
        self.axes[ 7].set_title('medium triangles')
        self.axes[ 8].set_title('paralleograms')
        self.axes[ 9].set_title('small triangles')

        img = self.gray.copy()
        img = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))

        self.axes[0].imshow(self.image)
        self.axes[0].axis('off')
        for i in range(1,10):
            self.axes[i].imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=-200)
            self.axes[i].axis('off')

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.02, right=0.98,
                            top=0.98,  bottom=0.02)


    def annotate(self, plot_no, ix, iy, text):
        ax = self.axes[plot_no]
        ax.annotate(text,  
                    xy=(ix, iy), 
                    xytext=(-3, 5),
                    textcoords='offset points', 
                    ha='right', 
                    va='bottom' )

    def add_points_to_plot(self, plot_no, set_of_points, **kwargs):
        '''
        Add point to the a plot. 
        Formatting can be done with the *kwargs*
        '''
        ax = self.axes[plot_no]

        for i, point in enumerate(set_of_points):
            ix, iy = self.to_image_coor(point)
            ax.plot(ix, iy, **kwargs)

            self.annotate(plot_no, ix, iy, str(i))

    def add_lines_to_plot(self, plot_no, set_of_lines, **kwargs):
        ax = self.axes[plot_no]

        for line in set_of_lines:
            p1, p2 = line
            ix1, iy1 = self.to_image_coor(p1)
            ix2, iy2 = self.to_image_coor(p2)
            ax.plot([ix1, ix2], [iy1, iy2], **kwargs)

    def add_triangles_to_plot(self, plot_no, list_of_triangles, ** kwargs):
        set_of_lines = set()
        for i, triangle in enumerate(list_of_triangles):
            p1, p2, p3 = triangle
            set_of_lines.add(Line(p1, p2))
            set_of_lines.add(Line(p2, p3))
            set_of_lines.add(Line(p3, p1))
            ix, iy = self.to_image_coor(triangle.center)
            self.annotate(plot_no, ix, iy, str(i))
        self.add_lines_to_plot(plot_no, set_of_lines, **kwargs)


    def add_piece_to_plot(self, plot_no, piece, **kwargs):
        list_of_points = list(piece.corners)
        list_of_points.append(list_of_points[0])
        N = len(list_of_points)
        set_of_lines = set()
        for i in range(N - 1):
            p1 = list_of_points[i]
            p2 = list_of_points[i+1]
            set_of_lines.add(Line(p1, p2))
        self.add_lines_to_plot(plot_no, set_of_lines, **kwargs)    

    def add_pieces_to_plot(self, plot_no, pieces, **kwargs):
        for piece in pieces:
            self.add_piece_to_plot(plot_no, piece, **kwargs) 


class TangramSolver():


    def __init__(self, filename = None):

        self.t = Tangram(filename)

    def solve(self):

        points = set(self.t.get_corners())
        edges = set(self.find_edges(points))

        self.t.add_lines_to_plot(1, edges, lw=1, color='r')
        self.t.add_points_to_plot(1, points, marker='o', ms=5, color='k')

        for repeat in range(FIND_REPEATS):    
            points = points.union(self.find_more_points(edges))
            edges = set(self.find_edges(points))

        point_neighbours = self.find_sq2_neighbours(points)
        triangles        = self.find_triangles(point_neighbours)
        neighbours       = self.find_triangle_neighbours(triangles)

        self.t.add_points_to_plot(2, points, marker='o', color='k')
        self.t.add_triangles_to_plot(3, triangles, lw=1, color='k')

        big_triangles    = self.find_big_triangles   (triangles, neighbours) 
        squares          = self.find_squares         (triangles, neighbours)
        medium_triangles = self.find_medium_triangles(triangles, neighbours) 
        parallelograms   = self.find_parallelograms  (triangles, neighbours)
        small_triangles  = self.find_small_triangles (triangles, neighbours)

        # plot some stuff...
        for plotno, color, pieces in [ (5, 'red',       big_triangles),    
                                       (6, 'yellow',    squares),
                                       (7, 'blue',      medium_triangles),
                                       (8, 'olivedrab', parallelograms),
                                       (9, 'purple',    small_triangles),  ]:
            self.t.add_pieces_to_plot(plotno, pieces, color=color, lw=2) 

        # here starts the fun
        for p1 in big_triangles:
         leftovers1 = p1.ouside_triangles(triangles)
         for p2 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers1, big_triangles):
          leftovers2 = p2.ouside_triangles(leftovers1)
          for p3 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers2, squares):
           leftovers3 = p3.ouside_triangles(leftovers2)
           for p4 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers3, medium_triangles):
            leftovers4 = p4.ouside_triangles(leftovers3)
            for p5 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers4, parallelograms):
             leftovers5 = p5.ouside_triangles(leftovers4)
             for p6 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers5, small_triangles):
              leftovers6 = p6.ouside_triangles(leftovers5)
              for p7 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers6, small_triangles):
               leftovers7 = p7.ouside_triangles(leftovers6)
               if len(leftovers7) == 0:

                print('Succes')
                good_pieces = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7]
                self.t.add_pieces_to_plot(4, good_pieces, color='k', lw=2) 
                return

        print('Failed')
        return

    def inside_tangram(self, line):
        N = 20   # oops, magic number..., anyway... :
        for i in range(1, N-1):
            line_length = line.length
            point = line.point_along(line_length * i / N )
            if not self.t.valid_value_at(point):
                return False
        return True

    def almost_equal(self, a, b, eps=EPSILON):
        return abs(a-b) < eps

    def is_nice_lenght(self, length, eps=EPSILON):
        for nice_length in NICE_LENGTHS:
            if abs(length - nice_length) < eps:
                return True
        return False

    def is_nice_angle(self, angle, eps=EPSILON_ANGLE):
        for nice_angle in [-180, -135, -90, -45, 45, 90, 135, 180]:
            if abs(angle - nice_angle) < eps:
                return True
        return False

    def is_nice_triangle_angle(self, angle, eps=EPSILON_ANGLE):
        for nice_angle in [-90, -45, 45, 90]:
            if abs(angle - nice_angle) < eps:
                return True
        return False


    def is_nice_edge(self, angle, edge):
        return (    self.is_nice_angle(angle)
                and self.is_nice_lenght(edge.length)
                and self.inside_tangram(edge) ) 

    def find_edges(self, points):
        edges = set()
        for center, p1, p2 in permutations(points, r=3):
            edge1 = Line(center, p1)
            edge2 = Line(center, p2)
            angle = edge1.angle(edge2)
            if self.is_nice_edge(angle, edge1):
                edges.add(edge1)
        return edges

    def find_more_points(self, edges, eps=EPSILON):
        results = set()
        for edge in edges:
            for length, splits in SPLITS.items():
                if self.almost_equal(length, edge.length, eps):
                    for split in splits:
                        results.add(edge.point_along(split))
        return results

    def triangle_inside_tangram(self, triangle, eps=EPSILON):
        '''
        checks some points inside the triangle to be inside
        the tangram
        '''
        global t # ugly, i know...
        p1, p2, p3 = triangle
        test_points = [
            p1 + ((p2 * 0.5 + p3 * 0.5) - p1) * 0.2,
            p2 + ((p3 * 0.5 + p1 * 0.5) - p2) * 0.2,
            p3 + ((p1 * 0.5 + p2 * 0.5) - p3) * 0.2,

            p1 + ((p2 * 0.5 + p3 * 0.5) - p1) * 0.8,
            p2 + ((p3 * 0.5 + p1 * 0.5) - p2) * 0.8,
            p3 + ((p1 * 0.5 + p2 * 0.5) - p3) * 0.8  ]

        return all([self.t.valid_value_at(tp) for tp in test_points]) 


    def reduce_neighbours(self, triangles, all_neighbours):
        neighbours = {}
        for t in triangles:
            neighbours[t] = [n for n in all_neighbours[t] if n in triangles]
        return neighbours

    def reduce_pieces(self, triangles, pieces):
        return [ p
                 for p in pieces
                 if set(p.triangles).issubset(set(triangles)) ]

    def find_sq2_neighbours(self, points, eps=EPSILON):
        '''
        Returns a dict with for every point a list with neighbouring
        points at roughly a SQ2 distance
        '''
        sq2_neighbours = {}
        for p1 in points:
            neighbours = []
            for p2 in points:
                if self.almost_equal(Line(p1, p2).length, SQ2, eps):
                     neighbours.append(p2)
            sq2_neighbours[p1] = neighbours
        return sq2_neighbours

    def find_triangles(self, sq2_neighbours, eps=EPSILON):
        triangles = set()
        for p1, neighbours in sq2_neighbours.items():
            for p2, p3 in permutations(neighbours, 2):
                if self.almost_equal(Line(p2, p3).length, TWO, eps):
                    triangle = Triangle(p1, p2, p3)
                    if self.triangle_inside_tangram(triangle):
                        triangles.add(triangle)
        return triangles

    def find_triangle_neighbours(self, triangles):
        neighbours = {}
        for t1 in triangles:
            neighbours[t1] = [ t2
                               for t2 in triangles
                               if t1.is_neighbour(t2) ]
        return neighbours

    def find_big_triangles(self, triangles, neighbours):
        '''
                     top1
                      /\
                     /  \
                    /_t1_\
                   /\ t2 /\
                  /  \  /  \ 
                 /_t3_\/_t4_\
               c1    top2    c2
        '''
        big_triangles = []
        for t1 in triangles:
            top1 = t1[0]
            for t2 in neighbours[t1]:
                top2 = t2[0]
                if not self.almost_equal(Line(top1, top2).length, TWO):
                    continue
                # now find two neighbours of this neighbour
                for t3, t4 in permutations(neighbours[t2], r=2):
                    if t3 == t1 or t4 == t1:
                        continue
                    p31 = t3[1]
                    p32 = t3[2]
                    p41 = t4[1]
                    p42 = t4[2]
                    c1, c2 = None, None
                    if self.almost_equal(Line(p31, p41).length, FOUR):
                        c1, c2 = p31, p41
                    if self.almost_equal(Line(p31, p42).length, FOUR):
                        c1, c2 = p31, p42
                    if self.almost_equal(Line(p32, p41).length, FOUR):
                        c1, c2 = p32, p41
                    if self.almost_equal(Line(p32, p42).length, FOUR):
                        c1, c2 = p32, p42
                    if c1 and c2:
                        corners   = (top1, c1, c2)
                        triangles = (t1, t2, t3, t4)
                        big_triangles.append(Piece(corners, triangles))
                        break
        return big_triangles

    def find_squares(self, triangles, neighbours):
        '''
                     top1
                      /\
                     /  \
                    /_t1_\
                    \ t2 /
                     \  / 
                      \/
                     top2 
        '''
        squares = []
        for t1 in triangles:
            top1 = t1[0]
            for t2 in neighbours[t1]:
                top2 = t2[0]
                if self.almost_equal(Line(top1, top2).length, TWO):
                    corners   = (top1, t1[1], top2, t1[2])
                    triangles = (t1, t2)
                    squares.append(Piece(corners, triangles))
                    break
        return squares

    def find_medium_triangles(self, triangles, neighbours):
        medium_triangles = []
        for t1 in triangles:
            top1 = t1[0]
            for t2 in neighbours[t1]:
                top2 = t2[0]
                if top1 != top2:
                    continue
                # now see if they are a medium square...
                for p1a, p1b, p2a, p2b in ((t1[1], t1[2], t2[1], t2[2]),
                                           (t1[1], t1[2], t2[2], t2[1]),
                                           (t1[2], t1[1], t2[1], t2[2]),
                                           (t1[2], t1[1], t2[2], t2[1])  ):
                    if (    p1a == p2a
                        and self.almost_equal(Line(p1b, p2b).length, 2 * SQ2)):

                        corners   = (p1a, p1b, p2b)
                        triangles = (t1, t2)
                        medium_triangles.append(Piece(corners, triangles))
                        break
        return medium_triangles

    def find_parallelograms(self, triangles, neighbours):
        parallelograms = []
        for t1 in triangles:
            for t2 in neighbours[t1]:
                st1 = set(t1)
                st2 = set(t2)
                opposites = st1.symmetric_difference(st2)
                both = st1.intersection(st2)
                p1, p2 = opposites
                if self.almost_equal(Line(p1, p2).length, SQ10):
                    b1, b2 = both
                    corners   = (p1, b1, p2,b2)
                    triangles = (t1, t2)
                    parallelograms.append(Piece(corners, triangles))
                    break
        return parallelograms

    def find_small_triangles(self, triangles, neighbours):
        small_triangles = []
        for t1 in triangles:
            small_triangles.append(Piece(tuple(t1), [t1]))
        return small_triangles


def get_random_image():
    '''
    return a random tangram image (file name), taken from:
    http://www.supercoloring.com/puzzle-games/
    stored in directory 'source_images', they are 480x480 pixels .png
    images, with a white background and tangram images in various
    colors.
    '''
    images = glob('source_images/*.png')
    return np.random.choice(images)

def main():
    filename = get_random_image()
    #filename = 'source_images/521-tangram-leopard-shape-puzzle-game.png'
    filename = 'source_images/116-tangram-cat-shape-puzzle-game.png'
    print(filename)
    ts = TangramSolver(filename)
    ts.solve()
    return ts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Point.set_epsilon(EPSILON)
    ts = main()
```

Comment: I do not think this question should be 'put on hold', despite's the title contains 'what went wrong'. The code is not broken, it might not implement  the right algorithms but works. Questions were primarily about coding style.

Comment: "it might not implement the right algorithms but works" Does it work as intended and solve the problem or not? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, the filename in the code provided lead me to documents like [this](http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/zif/pdf/2017/01/116-tangram-cat-shape-puzzle-game.pdf) and [this](http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/zif/pdf/2017/01/116_tangram_cat_solution-Puzzle%20game.pdf), which have a different cat figure. Can you provide the original picture you've used or a link towards it? The picture you used looks more like [this](http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/medium_no_levels/public/zif/2017/02/514-tangram-mink-shape-puzzle-game.png).

Comment: Also, please clarify for which Python version you've build this. It will NOT run on 2.x.

Comment: @Mast, I used Python 3, more precise for those who care: Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06), IPython 5.1.0

Comment: I'll get OpenCV up and running on my Python 3 environment and get back to you on whether I think this warrants re-opening. My first 2 comments still stand, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @Mast, I used several images, the cat image was a favorite because tangram is all about cats isn't it?, however the final code should have used `get_random_image`. The code works, i think/hope, as in: it implements my algorithm (mostly defined in `TangramSolver.solve`). The algorithm might be wrong, assumptions about estimations might be wrong (expressed in the 'constants' at the top of the code), source images might be wrong (doubt it)... . But my questions were about the Python code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66122/discussion-between-mast-and-jan-kuiken).

Comment: Why does `Piece` have an empty `__init__()`?

Comment: @200_success, you're right, `Piece.__init__()` can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

With half of the code it takes me too long to figure out why it's there. Code should either be properly commented or self documenting. Large parts of your code are neither. On top of that, there are scope issues which will lead to iffy maintainability later on.

Let's walk through it, top-to-bottom. Although I'll be skipping large parts to prevent this from getting even longer than the code itself.

```
# some 'constants'
EPSILON       = 0.2
EPSILON_ANGLE = 3.0
ZERO          = 0.0
ONE           = 1.0
TWO           = 2 * ONE
FOUR          = 2 * TWO
SQ2           = np.sqrt(TWO)
SQ10          = np.sqrt(10.0)

FIND_REPEATS  = 1
MAX_LENGTHS   = 6
SPLITS        = {}
for lengths in product([ZERO, SQ2, TWO], repeat=MAX_LENGTHS):
```

The writing style gives away they're supposed to be constants, so the only comment on it is unhelpful. Why is there a blank line between `SQ10` and `FIND_REPEATS`, but not between `SPLITS` and the `for` loop? Why are the constants being defined inconsistently?

Whatever you do, be consistent.

That entire for loop is usually replaced by a generator expression in modern Python. Although `numpy.indices` might be even faster, I'm not sure. But say you want to keep the loop around, is there anything to improve? Plenty.

```
for lengths in product([ZERO, SQ2, TWO], repeat=MAX_LENGTHS):
```

No. `lengths` is a plural, while it will only take one thing at a time. That this one thing is a collection of other things is irrelevant. Perhaps `collection` or `set` is better. Now nobody has a clue what's going on in the following.

```
length = sum(lengths)
splits = list(lengths)[:-1]
```

`length` is a sum of `lengths`. Why don't you call it `total_length` or `collection_total_length`?

```
splits = list(lengths)[:-1]
if not length in SPLITS:
    SPLITS[length] = set()
```

You're using both `splits` and `SPLITS` near to each other. Bloody confusing, get better names for both of them. Also, `SPLITS` isn't really a const in this context, is it? At the same time, you're missing one. `source_images`, your folder is used 3 times in the code. Either put it in a const next to this lot, or pass it as as a variable just like `filename` in `main`.

Many of your docstrings aren't of much help (refer to the first paragraph of this answer).

```
def set_up_plot(self):
    '''
    create a plot and add some stuff to it
    '''
```

Yes, let's add 'stuff' to the plot while setting it up. Are you initializing the plot? Why is there no mention of having to run interactively to even work?

```
# set matplotlib up,... interactive, delete old plots
```

Ah, there it is. In a comment, right after the docstring where it should've been. Perhaps `init_plot` would be a better name, since no actual data is added yet. That appears to happen here:

```
def add_points_to_plot(self, plot_no, set_of_points, **kwargs):
    '''
    Add point to the a plot. 
    Formatting can be done with the *kwargs*
    '''
```

Right? Because your code isn't exactly structured. Part of that is due to incredibly large functions like these `solve()` containing abominations like these:

```
    # here starts the fun
    for p1 in big_triangles:
     leftovers1 = p1.ouside_triangles(triangles)
     for p2 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers1, big_triangles):
      leftovers2 = p2.ouside_triangles(leftovers1)
      for p3 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers2, squares):
       leftovers3 = p3.ouside_triangles(leftovers2)
       for p4 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers3, medium_triangles):
        leftovers4 = p4.ouside_triangles(leftovers3)
        for p5 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers4, parallelograms):
         leftovers5 = p5.ouside_triangles(leftovers4)
         for p6 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers5, small_triangles):
          leftovers6 = p6.ouside_triangles(leftovers5)
          for p7 in self.reduce_pieces(leftovers6, small_triangles):
           leftovers7 = p7.ouside_triangles(leftovers6)
           if len(leftovers7) == 0:

            print('Succes')
            good_pieces = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7]
            self.t.add_pieces_to_plot(4, good_pieces, color='k', lw=2) 
            return
```

`p1` till`p7` are lousy names. What's a `p1`? What's a `p7`? How do they differ except for the order in which they're used?

```
good_pieces = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7]
```

Yes, there will only ever be 7 in a classic Tangram. Yes, it still looks hideous. A piece is called a `tan` by the way, so you could use that in your variable naming. `for tan in tans` is a construct I expected to see in your solver.

```
self.t.add_pieces_to_plot(4, good_pieces, color='k', lw=2)
```

And here come the magic numbers. You had constants for a reason, right? Why is this `4` exactly `4`? Is it the amount of sides to a puzzle? The amount of hours till self-destruct? We don't know. It's got something to do with pieces, but that's all we know. Add 4 pieces to a plot? But there are 7 tans and many more figures than 4. Apparently 'k' is a colour nowadays as well.

---

You got a great project running, but it's far from finished. If you leave it in it's current state and take your mind of it for a couple of days, can you still understand what it's doing and why? How about multiple weeks?

Lack of structure is how good projects die a silent death.

Comment: thanks for your comments, 'k' is used for black in matplotlib.